# How to get Jenkins job email notification for a particular person who raised pull request in GitHub

Tags: devops

How to get Jenkins job email notification for a particular person who raised pull request in GitHub

I have created pull request Jenkins job it will triggered when a pull request is triggered it was success works fine

but I am not understanding the email notification to receive only who raised the pull request

thanks advance

got solution

recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]

Comment: I got the solution we have to change the modifications through the cmd then add the global email and after that push into the central repository and then raise the pull request

and add Jenkinsfile    
recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]